# sharepoint 2010 cannot get global navigation nodes in code

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have sharepoint site and i want read in code global navigation information.

On properties page:

/_layouts/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx
I added "location","organization","98" nodes.

[image]

But when i am trying to get those nodes in code

```
  using (var site  = new Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite(URL))
            {
                using (var currentWeb = site.OpenWeb())
                {
               return currentWeb.Navigation.GlobalNodes;

            }
```

}

I have always those nodes:

- Home
- Quick launch
- SharePoint Top Navbar

Why i have those strange nodes and how to get real globan naviigation/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint's navigation is hierarchical. The hierarchy has exactly three nodes:

- Home — represents the single 'home' icon in the upper left;
- Quick launch — represents the quick launch menu at the left side of the page;
- Top navigation bar — represents the navigation bar at the top of the page.

You have to delve into subnodes of these node to find your three nodes — see the [`SPNavigationNode.Children`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.navigation.spnavigationnode.children.aspx) property. SharePoint lacks unique identifiers for navigation nodes so you have to rely on titles (display names).

---

**UPDATE:** Also please note that your code contains a serious design flaw. You are returning an object that's logically nested within a `SPWeb` out of the scope where the `SPWeb` instance is alive—i.e. out of the `using` statement. While this may work for navigation nodes generally such behavior will lead to errors. Those errors are often handled internally by SharePoint and result 'only' in logged error messages, but that's definitelly what your code should produce.

Comment: My links is presented there but Only with other links. Also i can just get links from  PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(currentWeb).Navigation.GlobalNavigation But there are a lot of trash there!!! which i not added. How to know which links mine from "Global Navigation" category and which sharepoint just added?

Comment: What 'trash'? If you were adding the navigation nodes programatically you could and a custom property into the node's property bag to keep some unique ID.

Comment: trash i mean that in sharepoint i see only "location" "organization" and "98" node but in code i have 12 - 13 or more! Because real trash was fetched. Thats why i hate sharepoint! ) And i already found that i can filter items by type. So i will get only nodes which i need. Will post part of code soon.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
var pubWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);
foreach (SPNavigationNode navigationNode in pubWeb.Navigation.GlobalNavigationNodes)
{
   //do stuff
}
```

Comment: How is this supposed to help the OP?